# If a Muslim fakes a baptism, is he considered an apostate?

Tags: christianity, apostasy, baptism

Think of a situation where a Muslim undergoes a baptism in a church in order to make Christians think that he's converting to Christianity (maybe he's doing some undercover work). But in reality, he is still a Muslim. Would that be shirk? Would that make him an apostate?

I read that from the Islamic perspective, a baptism will have no effect on your faith. You still remain a Muslim. So I don't expect a baptism to be shirk if the intention is to make Christians think he is converting to Christianity.

Answer (score 2):

**If there is a solid reason** for you to make christians think you are converted to christianity, than that's allowed.

What a solid reason might be **life threat**, extreme life threatening situation makes it allowed for you to say/do anything to save your life, but this does not mean one will stop trying to escape such situation/region to dar-us-salaam.

> **Whoever disbelieves in [i.e. denies] Allaah after his belief, except
>   for one who is forced [to renounce his religion] while his heart is
>   secure in faith. But those who [willingly] open their hearts to
>   disbelief, upon them is wrath from Allaah, and for them is a great
>   punishment.**[Quran 16:106]

Now **in the case you of some undercover work like spying** etc, if it is absolute necessary to do such job, **there are some conditions to follow, with which it is allowed.**

> **take every precaution for yourselves.** (Translation- Mohsin Khan) Quran(4:102)

Conditions include this activity **should be for the benefit of muslim ummah, not any individual or group.** **There is no other way to do this job** other than showing oneself as non-muslim. And that the **person will not do any major sin doing this job**, and is a **strong enough believer that he will not be deceived** by all things going around in that time. In short it is allowed with some conditions.

For details see [Muslims working as spies on enemies of Islam](http://www.islamweb.net/emainpage/index.php?page=showfatwa&Option=FatwaId&Id=82967).

### Allah knows best

Comment: But even if a muslim undergoes a baptism for no reason why should it be haram? Because it's not like a baptism really turns you into a christian. What if a muslim undergoes a baptism just to improve relations with a christian family (without the actual intention of becoming a christian)?

Comment: @curiosity that's a different case than, it will not be considered that one is doing so to lead people to believe he is christian, but it will be the case of participating in non-muslims rituals and things like that. And that will be a separate situation and separate question, which requires separate answer as well.